# knockout data-binding with ajax php result not working

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js and i am trying to create a table whose data comes from database using php ajax .data-binding not working with ajax php result, while if i create a table in same page with data-binding variable its working with that table.How can i make ajax results work with knockout . Thanks for helping
Below are my codes
data loading php:

```
include("db.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from codes");
$par='\$parent';
echo '<table class="table table-striped box"  >
<thead>
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>Code</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Starting Date</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Closing Date</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Select</b></td></tr></thead>
';
 echo '<tbody data-bind="foreach:{data:rows,as:\'Row\'}">';
echo "<tr>
        <td data-bind='text:Row.codes'></td>
        <td data-bind='text:Row.sDate'></td>
        <td data-bind='text:Row.eDate'></td>
        <td align=center><button data-bind='click:$par.selectRow' class='btn btn-orange'>Select</button></td>
        </tr>";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo "<tr >";
    echo "<td align=center data-bind='text:Row.codes'>$data[1]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center data-bind='text:Row.sDate'>$data[2]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center data-bind='text:Row.eDate'>$data[3]</td>";
    echo "<td align=center><button data-bind='click:$par.selectRow'  class='btn btn-orange addd'>Select</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

and my ajax code for loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"load.php",
                dataType:"html",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#codetable").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

and my knockout script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Row(codes,sDate,eDate){
        this.codes=codes;
        this.sDate=sDate;
        this.eDate=eDate;
    }
     var myRowViewModel = new function(){
        var current= this;
        this.SelectedRow = ko.observable(null);
        this.rows=ko.observableArray([
            new Row("45sd9e","10-08-2018",1000),
            new Row("45sd9e","10-08-2018",1000),
            ]);
        this.selectRow = function(Row){
            current.SelectedRow(Row)
            alert(Row.codes);
        }
}
    ko.applyBindings(myRowViewModel);
});
```

Comment: Hi, there is a Knockout tutorial than resolves your question:  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving (in the step 2).  Your PHP code should return Data, not HTML code, because knockout takes care to show the data from your View Model (`myRowViewModel`).  Hope this helps.  :-)

Comment: that doesn't solved my problem, Well now i have changed my data to json and its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now i have figured out what problem was.I changed my data to json and its working now.